# Is there any way to simulate a slow connection between my server and an iPad (without installing anything on the server)?

Tags: performance, testing, ipad, throttling

Some of our webapp users have difficulty on slower connections.
I"m trying to get a better idea of what that "speed barrier is" so I'd like to be able to test a variety of connection speeds.

I've found ways to do this on Windows but no on the iPad, so I'm looking more for some sort of proxy service that'll work with any device (not running ON that device)

I did find an article about [using the CharlesProxy and providing a connection](http://roderick.dk/2012/05/11/simulate-slow-web-connections/) to another device, but I was hoping for something simpler (need not be free)

*Constraints*
* We are on a shared server so we can't install anything and we are limited in our control over that server.
* I'd like to test an iPad, Android Tablet, Windows PC.

Comment: This recent ['Rate limit the FCC'](https://neocities.org/blog/the-fcc-is-now-rate-limited) blog post probably has what you are looking for, as long as you know the iPad's IP address. Rules for [Nginx](https://gist.github.com/kyledrake/e6046644115f185f7af0) and [Apache](https://gist.github.com/m1/e5f1f190ba309b500f0a) are linked to at the bottom. No install needed. Is that suitable?

Comment: Do you know your way around a wireless router? Check and see if there are any throttle settings in the admin panel.

Comment: I think @MonkeyZeus's suggestion is a good one. You could probably use some QoS settings in a router that lacks other throttle settings to simulate. Another option would be to use the Windows throttle method, but then broadcast a wireless network from Windows (look up "Windows hosted network") and share the throttle connection with that wireless connection. A hack, but it'd do the job, I think.

Comment: I use Charles Proxy for all of my development testing and it's really great. The advantage I find is that it's not just going to slow the connection, it'll also give you great, usable, information about what's being sent/received and this may help solve the issue as well as replicate it...

Answer (score 1):

you could change (reduce) the tcp-stack buffer size for a connection (client IP) but that requires root priviliges